# Project on Google go, imports of libraries

Tags: import, go, dependencies, project

everyone.

I am new to Go language and currently I am trying to understand the basics of building Go applications. I met the following problem.

For example, I am using other libraries in my project. I have them locally, on my computer, so my project works fine.

I am loading my code on github and another programmer download it. As I understand, my code won't work, because this programmer doesn't have the libraries I used.

So the question is: What is the best way to share my project with all libraries it has? Should I upload these libraries in the separate repositories? Then to use my project, people need to look inside the code to detect which libraries I am using to download them one by one?

For example, in Java there is such thing like Maven or Ant, which downloads all required dependencies. Is there any tools like this for Go?

Let's call the main file of my project main.go
And I am using my own library: mathutil.go

what is the best way to make this project run on other computers?

Comment: Do you know that Go has no libraries but packages? Please read at least some of the information on http://golang.org before asking here.

Answer (score 3):

Go's dependencies work very much like using Maven or IVY transitive dependencies.  When someone does "go get" of your package, anything you depend on will automatically download.

For example, in your source:

```
import "github.com/foo/bar"
```

go will automatically download that to your $GOPATH/src/github.com/foo/bar along with your code.

Assuming the third party libs you use are hosted in a public repo (ie: github) then people don't need to do anything.

If the libraries you used are not available on a public repo, you will need to post them somewhere assuming their licensing allows.

Take a look at [golang.org/doc/code.html](http://golang.org/doc/code.html#remote) for more details

Comment: Go will not download imported libraries automatically. If you `go get` code into the workspace it dependencies will be fetched automatically. If you need to fetch dependencies to your own code you can do a `go get path/to/own/...`

Comment: @mbanzon wouldn't a `got get -u all` do that though?

Comment: Thanks mbanzon, updated to be more clear.  Also, yes, I believe "go get -u all" will do that too, but it also may do a bunch of stuff you don't want (ie: stomp on stuff you are working on)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, guys. Looks like dependency management in Go is much easier than I thought.